# Create Folder on Google Teamdrives in PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client, google-workspace

I'm trying to do a script that create a simple folder dynamically on my TeamDrive google.

I succeed to do that on my Drive but not on my TeamDrive.
It's seems to be like i do not see them.

My code :

```
$TeamDriveList = new Google_Service_Drive_TeamDriveList($client);
print_r($TeamDriveList);
```

The result :

```
Google_Service_Drive_TeamDriveList Object ( [collection_key:protected] =>     teamDrives [kind] => [nextPageToken] => [teamDrivesType:protected] => Google_Service_Drive_TeamDrive [teamDrivesDataType:protected] => array [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array ( ) [modelData:protected] => Array ( ) [processed:protected] => Array ( ) )
```

If i'm trying that with Google Console test , i see :

200

```
{
 "kind": "drive#teamDriveList",
 "teamDrives": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#teamDrive",
   "id": "0AB0TME2EwUCRUk9PVA"
  },
  {
   "kind": "drive#teamDrive",
   "id": "0AD2eQbRih1DZUk9PVA"
  }
 ]
}
```

​
Certainly my PHP Code is not correct.

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: There is no error but the answer doesn't contain the list of my two teamdrives. My objective is only to try to create one folder on one teamdrive in php with api php google .

Comment: Hi, did you have any idea ? @DaImTo